# Qt QSslSocket "The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted"

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, server, qsslsocket

i want to connect server with QSslSocket and on server i get soketSslError "The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted" , but  i dont understand why i have this error.

On first step was generated file for server and client with openssl

```
$openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout ca.key -x509 -days 500 -out ca.crt
$openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout client01.key -out client01.csr
$openssl ca -config ca.config -in  client01.csr -out client01.crt -batch
```

in c++ server / client

**On server:**

***start server***

```
if (listen(QHostAddress::Any,this->connectingPort)) {
        std::cout<<"Server start on port: "<<this->connectingPort<<std::endl;
        return true;
    } else {
        std::cout<<"Cant start server. "<<errorString().toStdString().c_str()<<std::endl;
        return false;
    }
```

***incomingConnection***

```
    QFile keyFile("ca.key");
    if (!keyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        delete this->sslSocket;
        qDebug()<<"Cant open file: "<<keyFile.fileName();
        return false;
    }
    QByteArray pasp ="qwerty";
    QSslKey key(keyFile.readAll(),QSsl::Rsa,QSsl::Pem,QSsl::PrivateKey,pasp);
    if (key.isNull()) {
        delete this->sslSocket;
        qDebug()<<"key in file "<<keyFile.fileName()<<" is empty";
        return false;
    }
    keyFile.close();

    this->sslSocket->setPrivateKey(key);
    this->sslSocket->setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyPeer);
    this->sslSocket->setLocalCertificate("ca.crt");
    this->sslSocket->startServerEncryption();
```

**on client side:**

```
this->sslSocket->setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyPeer);


QFile keyFile("client01.key");

if (!keyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    delete this->sslSocket;
    qDebug()<<"Cant open file: "<<keyFile.fileName();
    return ;
}
QByteArray pasp ="qwerty";
QSslKey key(keyFile.readAll(),QSsl::Rsa,QSsl::Pem,QSsl::PrivateKey,pasp);
if (key.isNull()) {
    delete this->sslSocket;
    qDebug()<<"key in file "<<keyFile.fileName()<<" is empty";
    return ;
}
keyFile.close();

this->sslSocket->setPrivateKey(key);

this->sslSocket->setLocalCertificate("client01.crt");

this->sslSocket->connectToHostEncrypted("192.168.0.10",1258);

if (!this->sslSocket->waitForEncrypted()) {
    qDebug()<<"error: "<<sslSocket->errorString();
}
```

and when i connecting from client i get on server error

```
soket ssl error
"The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted" 
"The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted" 
socketError:  QAbstractSocket::SocketError( 13 )
```

any idea what i do wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Qt Creator 3.0.1
Based on Qt 5.2.1 (GCC 4.8.2, 64 bit)

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Qt Creator 3.0.1
Based on Qt 5.2.1 (GCC 4.8.2, 64 bit)
Built on Apr 9 2014 at 09:12:59

Comment: Please have a look here, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-7200 they say this was fixed in 5.3

Comment: Hello - what is your `this` referring to?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try this on the server:

```
QList<QSslCertificate> cert = QSslCertificate::fromPath(QLatin1String("your-certificate.pem"));
QSslError error(QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate, cert.at(0));
QList<QSslError> expectedSslErrors;
expectedSslErrors.append(error);

this->sslSocket.ignoreSslErrors(expectedSslErrors);
```

Comment: i can mistake but as i understand  in _"your-certificate.pem"_ i add client01.pem file, but nothing change. 
this is all file that i have: ca.crt, ca.key,  client01.key,client01.crt, client01.pem

Answer (score 1):

**probleb has been resolved**

what i doen:
update version Qt for 5.5
and generated new ssl certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.key -out key.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

in server:

```
sslServer.setSslLocalCertificate("key.pem");
sslServer.setSslPrivateKey("key.key");
sslServer.setSslProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);
```

in client:

```
sslSocket.addCaCertificates("key.pem");
```